# php executes before submit button is hit

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

I am trying to connect to my db via PDO like any other of my pages so I just copied and pasted the same code from my other page nothing changed (same db and user and such) and now I am getting this error :

> [Wed Dec 26 22:51:49 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:
> Undefined index: anum in /var/www/signinpage.php on line 69 [Wed Dec
>
> 26 22:51:49 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined
> index: first in /var/www/signinpage.php on line 70 [Wed Dec 26
>
> 22:51:49 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined
> index: last in /var/www/signinpage.php on line 71 [Wed Dec 26 22:51:49
> 2012]
>
> [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: why in
> /var/www/signinpage.php on line 72 [Wed Dec 26 22:51:49 2012] [error]
>
> [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: comments in
> /var/www/signinpage.php on line 73 [Wed Dec 26 22:51:49 2012] [error]
>
> [client 127.0.0.1] SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:
> 1048 Column 'anum' cannot be null

I think the script is starting before the submit button his which I don't want to happen as the script is an insert and form validation script.

these are the connect lines ( where error is being caused )

```
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password="testdbpass"; // Mysql password
$db_name="test"; // Database name

// Connect to server via PHP Data Object
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;", $username, $password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

and this is the full code :

```
<?php 
//Starting session
session_start();


$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password="testdbpass"; // Mysql password
$db_name="test"; // Database name

// Connect to server via PHP Data Object
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;", $username, $password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


// Validation starts here  
    
    if(empty($_POST) === false) {
    $errors = array();
        $anum       =   $_POST['anum'];
        $first      =   $_POST['first'];
        $last       =   $_POST['last'];
        $why        =   $_POST['why'];
        $comments   =   $_POST['comments'];
    
    if (empty($anum) === true || empty($first) === true || empty($last) === true){  
        $errors[] = 'Form is incomplete please revise it!';
} 
    else {

    if(ctype_alnum($anum) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'A number can only consist of alphanumeric characters!';
}
    if(strlen($anum) > 9) {
        $errors[] = 'A number is incorrect!';
}
    if(strlen($anum) < 9) {
        $errors[] = 'A number is incorrect!';
}
    if(ctype_alpha($first) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'First mame must only contain alphabetical characters!';
}
    if(ctype_alpha($last) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'Last name must only contain alphabetical characters!';
}
    if(empty($why)) {
        $errors[] = 'Please make sure to select the proper reasoning for your vistit today!';
} 
    elseif ($why ==='Other' && empty($comments)) {
        $errors[] = 'Please explain the nature of your visit in the comments box!';
}
    if (strlen($comments) < 15) {
        $errors[] = 'Your explaination is short, please revise!';
}
    if(strlen($comments) > 45) {
        $errors[] = 'Your explaintion is to long, please revise!';
}
}
    if (empty($errors) === true) {
        header('location: signedin.php');
            exit(); 
}
} // Validations ends here


// We start our insert statement here!

try {
        $query = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `students` (anum, first, last, why, comments) 
                               VALUES (:anum, :first, :last, :why, :comments)");
        
        $query->execute(
                        array(
                                'anum'  => $_POST['anum'],
                                'first'     => $_POST['first'],
                                'last'      => $_POST['last'],
                                'why'       => $_POST['why'],
                                'comments'  => $_POST['comments']
                                )); 
    }
            catch (PDOException $e) 
    {
            error_log($e->getMessage());
            die($e->getMessage());
    }
$dbh = null;

?>
<html> 
<body>
<title>Student Signin Form</title>
<table width="300" align="center" cellpadding="0"
cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<?php 
    if(empty($errors) === false) {
        echo '<h3>';
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
            echo '<center><li>' , $error, '</li></center>';
        }
        
        echo '<h3>';
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr> 

<tr colspan="3"><center></center><strong>Student Signin Form</strong></tr>
    <p>Student ID Number: <input type="text" name="anum" <?php if (isset($_POST['anum']) === true) {echo 'value="' ,$_POST['anum'], '"';} ?> />
    <p>First Name: <input type="text" name="first" <?php if (isset($_POST['first']) === true) {echo 'value="' ,$_POST['first'], '"';} ?> />
    <p>Last Name: <input type="text" name="last" <?php if (isset($_POST['last']) === true) {echo 'value="' ,$_POST['last'], '"';} ?> />
    <p>How may we help you? <select name="why" />
                <option value=""></option> 
                <option value="Appeal">Appeal</option>
                <option value="Other">Other: Please specify the nature of your visit bellow</option>
                </select>
</tr>



<br>

<P>If other please describe the issue you are having.</P>
<textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="comments" <?php if (isset($_POST['comments']) === true) {echo 'value="' ,$_POST['comments'], '"';} ?>></textarea>



<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send"/>

</form>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just restarted mysql and now I am getting another error that "anum" is empty integrity constraint. I think the script is being run without me hitting the "submit" button.

Comment: Check out the line where you have `mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;` Perhaps you should remove the ending semicolon?

Comment: I jut fixed the error by restart mysql now I am getting errors that there are empty form data being passed because I have the script on the same page as the form itself. Now my problem is that the page script is running before actually hitting submit.

Comment: Please indent your code properly. It's nearly impossible to tell how your braces are placed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend your

```
if(empty($_POST) === false) {
```

block to the end of database operation. Put it's closing `}` after `$dbh = null;` line.